# Heroku Cannot Find Module (Model File)

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am getting a model import error in my `Node.js` application when deploying to `Heroku`.

```
2016-02-10T20:40:04.712617+00:00 app[web.1]: > node ./bin/www
2016-02-10T20:40:04.712615+00:00 app[web.1]: > comic@0.0.0 start /app
2016-02-10T20:40:05.770633+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2016-02-10T20:40:05.770629+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:341
2016-02-10T20:40:05.770637+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
2016-02-10T20:40:05.770636+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '../models/Comic'
2016-02-10T20:40:05.770638+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
2016-02-10T20:40:05.770634+00:00 app[web.1]:     ^
2016-02-10T20:40:05.770640+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
2016-02-10T20:40:05.770641+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
2016-02-10T20:40:05.770639+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
2016-02-10T20:40:05.770642+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
2016-02-10T20:40:05.770637+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
2016-02-10T20:40:05.770640+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/routes/create.js:2:13)
2016-02-10T20:40:05.770643+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
2016-02-10T20:40:05.770642+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
2016-02-10T20:40:05.804819+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

I have tried doing `heroku run bash` and running `require('./models/Comic')` from `node` session in `app` and `require('../models/Comic')` from within a subdirectory of `/app/routes/` to test that `require` works.

The only instances of the `require` for `Comic` are in the three routes within the `routes` folder. They all have the exact same `var myVar = require('../models/Comic');`.

Comment: As far as I've seen, you don't have Comic module installed, or you were searching for Comic in your models directory, please double check what your directory structure looks like and see if you have a Comic inside models. Can you host code for a while so that we can look at it and see what the error is? Or at least show us what the directory and file structure looks like.

Comment: It's not a module, it's just a model file that I made myself. The only instances of that model being required is in three of my routers. It runs locally fine if that helps. I will try to post directory structure in main question.

Comment: I could do a little better if I could see content of .gitignore, and directory structure, are you sure you have that file uploaded to heroku?

Comment: From `heroku run bash` in the `/app` directory:
`~ $ ls models/Comic.js`
returns `models/Comic.js`

Comment: Did you export everything on Comic.js and is node and express on server and on your local machine have same version? maybe something has changed, can't really go through without peeking into project.

Comment: When I first deployed I could see `Comic.ts` and `comic.js` which I then changed to `Comic.js`.. does that matter?

Comment: Are you on windows? Windows is crappy and is case insensitive whereas heroku is on awesome Linux based OS which is case sensitive. Could you do a check? If that works, I'm gonna write an answer which speaks against windows, it's my dream come true :)

Comment: I am using Mac OS X.

Comment: Sorry about my comment earlier, :D I feel stupid, could you still do a check?

Comment: It seems that heroku is compiling the `Comic.ts` file to `comic.ts` file and then when I change the filename it still doesn't want to persist. Do I need to do something on heroku to make the filename change persist?

Comment: Figured it out @NishchalGautam, thanks for your help! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that `heroku`:

a) Takes the info from Git. Even though I had made case changes in my local files and pushed to Git, the case wasn't changed. Then when the file was required on `heroku` which uses Linux, it could not find the file.

b) Only changing the name of the file from `heroku run bash` didn't seem to have any affect. I am assuming I wasn't doing some sort of deployment step or that I needed to do something extra (I tried `heroku restart` but no dice).

Hope this can help someone else.